# Focus on the block in IE 11

Tags: html, css, focus, internet-explorer-11

I have 3 blocks

```css
.block1 {
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
}

.block1 *:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
}

.block2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class='block1'>
  <span>Block1</span>
  <div class="block2">
    <span>Block2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
    <span>Block2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In chrome, I can focus just on interactive elements(buttons, inputs, and others) but in IE 11 I can focus the block by mouse and styles applies to this block

Screenshot:
[image]

How can I avoid applying focus styles to the block in IE?

Answer (score 0):

Change this to your code and check once.

```
.block1 *:focus:not(.block2) {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Yes, It's ok if I have several blocks, but in the real project, I have a lot dynamically rendered block and also I can focus on tables, sections, and other blocks

Trying to find more universal solution

Thank for your answer :)